# How to find which document is belong to which cluster?

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling, nlp

I am new in natural language processing and I found [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/topic-modeling-and-latent-dirichlet-allocation-in-python-9bf156893c24) interesting tutorial which describes how to do the topic modeling.

Available [data](https://www.kaggle.com/therohk/million-headlines/data) for this tutorial

Source code: [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/topic-modeling-and-latent-dirichlet-allocation-in-python-9bf156893c24)

The above code can provide topic modeling using LDA and generates the k number of topic. My question is how can I find which document belongs to which topic (cluster)? Like the example shown in figure [here](https://imgur.com/hA0dqUL). I wondering something like:

> publish_date:20030219 with text (aba ...) belongs to topic 1 cluster
>   or ..

I already read the post such as:
[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984841/topic-distribution-how-do-we-see-which-document-belong-to-which-topic-after-doi/20991190) or [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448833/topicmodel-how-to-query-documents-by-topic-model-topic) but still, I couldn't get my answer.

I also tried Matlab text analytic toolbox but I couldn't figure that out yet.

It would be great if you can provide me any help.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass your document through like this:

```
a = lda_model[bow_corpus[:]]
```

Create your topic arrays:

```
topic_0=[]
topic_1=[]
topic_2=[]

for i in a:
    topic_0.append(i[0][1])
    topic_1.append(i[1][1])
    topic_2.append(i[2][1])
```

Then put it in a csv and find the max value

```
d = {'topic_0': topic_0,
     'topic_1': topic_1,
     'topic_2': topic_2}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_csv("YourCSV.csv", index=True, mode = 'a')
```

You can also look at the scores for a single row:

```
lda_model[bow_corpus[123]]
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your comment and code. It helped me to understand more about lda. I would like to know if there is any way to only save the output of the highest prob for each document topic. Like: document 1 belong to topic 2 with the highest probability of i.e. 0.97. Thank you

Comment: You can write a formula like: if max(topic_0, topic_1, topic_2) = topic_1 then 'topic_1' elseif max(topic_0, topic_1, topic_2) = topic_2 then 'topic_2' else 0 endif